# If traversing a tree data-structure in the direction away from the root-node (and toward the leaves), is that direction "up" or "down"?

Tags: tree

I am currently debugging someone else's code that flips the "ups" and "downs" relative to the convention I am accustomed to.

Comment: In your context, the logical expectation would be that ***down*** implies **depth-first-**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Down. As @Shamim mentioned, this aligns with the "depth-first" terminology.

In computer science, trees are usually drawn with the root node on top, and the leaves at the bottom (i.e. upside down). It makes little sense but I presume it's easier than correctly estimating how much space you'll need to draw it "the right way up".

There's a similar question on [Quora: Why are trees in computer science generally drawn upside-down from how trees are in real life?](http://www.quora.com/Binary-Trees/Why-are-trees-in-computer-science-generally-drawn-upside-down-from-how-trees-are-in-real-life)

And the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure) seems to agree.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend how you draw the Tree on paper, but a better term to use is traversing deeper. That is nodes away from root are located deeper than nodes closer, as used in the term `Depth-First-Search`.